# How can I get a list of CPT inside a plugin file?

Tags: plugin-development

I have used the following code but it's providing me the CPT list on front-end files like page-template. but it doesn't provide me the CPT list **inside a plugin file**, what can I do to get the CPT list inside a plugin file?

```
$args=array(
    'public'                => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    '_builtin'              => false
);  
$post_types = get_post_types($args);
```

Comment: when you run this is important, it's likely the problem is that you asked for a list of CPT's before the CPT's were registered

Comment: Thanks Tom,
Yes, but how can I call this after CPT get registered?

Comment: You would need to call it on an action that happens after the post type is registered. It's not a good idea to make function calls to do work at the top level of a plugin file, it's almost always better to do it inside an action. Note that code in WP is code, there's no special case for wether it was in a themes functions.php or if it was in a plugin file, it's all loaded together, there are no sandboxes or containers separating your code and the code of other plugins, and there's nothing special about running code in a plugin file